# In Google Sheets, how can I assign a number to an arbitrary value?

Tags: casting, google-sheets, integer, type-conversion

For example, how can I do something like:

```
=AVERAGE(TOINTIF(A1:A17, "Fifth", 5), TOINTIF(A1:A17, "Sixth", 6), [...])
```

, TOINTIF(range, query, value) being a function that takes all the values in a range that meet a condition and places them into an array of instances a specified number.

Can this be done in GSheets?

Comment: can you share a sheet ?

Comment: What do you mean? Share as in share with someone else? If so, then yes.

Comment: If you can,  share a sample spreadsheet with some  sample data and I can show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need if statements - probably combined with arrayformula:

```
=sort(ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A17="Fifth", 5,)),1,true)
```

if you dont need them grouped together you can remove the sort and leave

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A17="Fifth", 5,))
```

to nest them:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A17="Fifth", 5,if(A1:A17="Sixth", 6,))
```

Comment: How can you use an =IF() statement to compare a range with a single value? Wouldn't it return false if even one of them does not meet the condition?

Comment: No this is why it is wrapped in array formula

Comment: What is the difference between sorting and not sorting?